# Why doesn't gcsfuse return to the command prompt after mounting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fuse, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I've successfully installed [gcsfuse](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse). When I run it, it prints `File system has been successfully mounted` but I don't get back to the shell prompt. (See the transcript below.) What am I doing wrong?

Confirming that the bucket exists:

```
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ gsutil ls

Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install
them, please run:
 $ gcloud components update

gs://daniella/
gs://test-daniella-nearline/
gs://test-yakov/
gs://yossi-fuse-bucket/
```

Installing prerequisites:

```
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ sudo apt-get install wget fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fuse
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 74.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 179 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main fuse amd64 2.9.0-2+deb7u2 [74.2 kB]
Fetched 74.2 kB in 0s (1,953 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package fuse.
(Reading database ... 20074 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fuse (from .../fuse_2.9.0-2+deb7u2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_4WmsnD/scripts/local-premount/gce-disable-growroot: 7: .: Can't open /scripts/functions
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up fuse (2.9.0-2+deb7u2) ...
Creating fuse group...
Adding group `fuse' (GID 105) ...
Done.
udev active, skipping device node creation.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_PqrQoB/scripts/local-premount/gce-disable-growroot: 7: .: Can't open /scripts/functions
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ sudo adduser $USER fuse
Adding user `ybaruy_gmail_com' to group `fuse' ...
Adding user ybaruy_gmail_com to group fuse
Done.
```

Installing gcsfuse, as described [here](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md):

```
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ wget https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/releases/download/v0.6.0/gcsfuse_v0.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
--2015-08-04 05:50:34--  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/releases/download/v0.6.0/gcsfuse_v0.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.129
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.129|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/30325550/e406280c-3aab-11e5-92fd-72a098ee49be.gz?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dgcsfuse_v0.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application/octet-stream&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1438667495&Signature=D4Dq3DdtDIuhmhz4MYCfbIWqvbg%3D [following]
--2015-08-04 05:50:35--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/30325550/e406280c-3aab-11e5-92fd-72a098ee49be.gz?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dgcsfuse_v0.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application/octet-stream&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1438667495&Signature=D4Dq3DdtDIuhmhz4MYCfbIWqvbg%3D
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.2.40
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.2.40|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4002177 (3.8M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `gcsfuse_v0.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz'

100%[========================================================================================>] 4,002,177   1.09M/s   in 4.2s

2015-08-04 05:50:40 (939 KB/s) - `gcsfuse_v0.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz' saved [4002177/4002177]

ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -zxf gcsfuse_v0.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ sudo chmod g+rw /dev/fuse
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ sudo chgrp fuse /dev/fuse
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ mkdir mount-point
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ logout
Connection to 146.148.112.111 closed.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Session stopped
    - Press <return> to exit tab
    - Press r to restart session
    - Press s to save terminal output to file





RECONNECTING, PLEASE WAIT...




X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Linux test-fuse 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1~bpo70+1 (2015-06-08) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Tue Aug  4 05:45:22 2015 from pavel.iucc.ac.il
```

Running gcsfuse:

```
ybaruy_gmail_com@test-fuse:~$ gcsfuse yossi-fuse-bucket mount-point
2015/08/04 05:51:44.524655 Warning: low file rlimit of 1024 will cause cached content to be frequently evicted. Consider raising with `ulimit -n`.
2015/08/04 05:51:44.954706 File system has been successfully mounted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected that the `gcsfuse` command doesn't return to the shell—it runs in the foreground until the file system is unmounted (using `fusermount -u`) or it receives `SIGINT`, usually via you pressing Ctrl-C. See the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) for more details.

If you want to interact with the file system while it is running in the foreground, you'll need to open another SSH session and do it there. Alternatively, you can use a helper program like [`daemon`](http://libslack.org/daemon/) to turn gcsfuse into a daemon running in the background, and even set it up in your `fstab`. See the section called ["Running as a daemon"](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#running-as-a-daemon) in the documentation for details.